# Handling exceptions and other conditions in decorators

Tags: python-3.x, exception, python-decorators

```
def test_a():
    try:
        # If everything is working well
        return {'status': True, 'message': 'This is a problem'}
    except Exception as e:
        return {'status': False, 'message': f'Exception is raised {e}'}


def test_b(a):
    try:
        if type(a) is not int:
            return {'status': False, 'message': 'This is a problem'}
         return {'status': True, 'message': 'We are good'}
    except Exception as e:
        return {'status': False, 'message': f'Exception is raised {e}'}



if __name__ == '__main__':
    a_res = test_a()
    if not a_res['status']:
        print(test_a())

    b_res = test_a()
    if not b_res['status']:
        print(test_b())
```

This is the kind of approach that works well in case if I want to debug/log the results when working with a big code base.

But as the number of methods keep increasing. The number of checks that needs to be done to ensure that the method is returning true and working well can make the codebase big and redundant.

What is the elegant way to replicate the same without such verbose repetitive checks.
Does the decorators help? or any design pattern that address this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a decorator to handle the error checking and logging for your functions.

```
def error_handler(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if isinstance(result, dict) and result.get('status') is False:
                print(result)
            return result
        except Exception as e:
            return {'status': False, 'message': f'Exception is raised {e}'}
    return wrapper

@error_handler
def test_a():
    # If everything is working well
    return {'status': True, 'message': 'This is a problem'}

@error_handler
def test_b(a):
    if type(a) is not int:
        return {'status': False, 'message': 'This is a problem'}
    return {'status': True, 'message': 'We are good'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(test_a())
    print(test_b(10))
```

Output:

```
{'status': True, 'message': 'This is a problem'}
{'status': True, 'message': 'We are good'}
```

Comment: That works, but how can this be used if the test_b execution should happen only if test_a return status as true?

Comment: To achieve that, you can modify the test_b function to accept a parameter result which represents the result of test_a. Then, you can check if result['status'] is True before executing test_b. Like this: @error_handler
def test_b(result=None):
    if result is None or result.get('status') is not True:
        return {'status': False, 'message': 'test_a failed or not executed'}
    if type(result) is not int:
        return {'status': False, 'message': 'This is a problem'}
    return {'status': True, 'message': 'We are good'}